# Rspec/Capybara matching data across rows and columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I've got HTML looking something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Customer Alice
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Status: enrolled / signed
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Customer Boris
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Status: signed
  </div>
</div>
```

Having some challenges with matching across rows and columns.

When using Rspec/Capybara, I update details for `Boris` so that his status becomes `enrolled / signed` i.e.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Customer Alice
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Status: enrolled / signed
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Customer Boris
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Status: enrolled / signed
  </div>
</div>
```

This is easy to confirm on-screen visually, by a human.

Since I am using Capybara and Poltergeist :), how do I easily match to confirm that Boris's status is expected to be `enrolled / signed` for the spec?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I started going down the line of embedding generated data into HTML the divs (e.g. so Boris's column div for ``enrolled / signed`` has a data or id attribute that I can select on and then match. This seems involved so was wondering if there was a more idiomatic approach (especially as I am also new at Rspec/Capybara).

Comment: Have you tried write a test? Stackoverflow it's not about write code for you. This can help to start http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-write-rails-view-test-with-rspec/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
row = find('.row', text: 'Customer Boris')
expect(row).to have_text('enrolled')
```

would do what you want - if you wanted to do it all in one you could pass a regex for the text match so

expect(page).to have_selector('.row', text: /Customer Boris.*enrolled/)

or something like that

Comment: Thanks @tom-walpole :) I ended up going with the regex approach as my actual HTML is more heavily nested (React) and more ambiguous. Still getting my head around Rspec approach.